# Easiest proof of computability of homotopy groups of spheres

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, constructive-mathematics, homotopy-groups-of-sphere

Has it gotten easier to prove all homotopy groups of spheres are computable? I don’t care if the computation is inefficient, what’s the easiest proof? Are we still stuck doing Postnikov towers?

Comment: Citing from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Computational_methods) (concerning the method opposite to the Postnikov one), "In principle this gives an effective algorithm for computing all homotopy groups of any finite simply connected simplicial complex, but in practice it is too cumbersome to use for computing anything other than the first few nontrivial homotopy groups as the simplicial complex becomes much more complicated every time one kills a homotopy group."

Comment: Curtís showed (in the seventies, I think, one of the first papers in the old Topology journal) that the homotopy groups of a connected free simplicial group coincides with those of its projection to nilpotency class $2^n$ up to dimension $n$. One can compute the homology of the Moore complex of a free nilpotent simplicial group in an inefficient but algorithmic way. The same result was later obtained by Quillen and Bousfield-Kan by slightly different techniques.

Comment: Thanks but neither of those helps—the quote from the Wikipedia article references two papers in French and I need something in English, and the rest of the Wikipedia article is absolutely insulting crap for calling things that aren’t really algorithms “computations”. For the Curtis/Quillen stuff I’d really like a reference. When I was in grad school I found it very frustrating that topologists would not grasp the concept of “total recursive function” sufficiently well to appreciate that the “computations” discussed in the textbooks were not actually effective.

Comment: When I was in grad school I found it very frustrating that topologists would not grasp the concept of “total recursive function” sufficiently well to appreciate that the “computations” discussed in the textbooks were not actually effective. My conclusion: no one has improved on Kan’s original proof that there really was an effective computation in all the years since; even in the special case of spheres that I am asking about.  To reiterate: I don’t need a fast algorithm, just an easy proof that there IS an algorithm.

Comment: @JoeShipman Saying that Wikipedia's use of "computation" for things that are not algorithms is "absolutely insulting crap" seems a little excessive to me...

Comment: Homotopy theory has a tendency to call things "computations" when they reduce the computation of something to some relatively standard other object -- but that object itself may be just some mathematically-presented object, i.e. often it is not of a finitary nature.  I think the abuse of language, while occasionally frustrating, is understandable, given that specialization has this tendency to put people into bubbles where they are talking with like-minded folks.   Whenever you talk to a new person, you have to get used to whatever dialect they are speaking, before your can really converse.

Comment: I have never thought that the use of "computation" as a synonym for "calculation" was unique to topologists, but maybe it is, and I never noticed. A web search for "computation of the Chow ring" reveals that some algebraic geometers use the word "computation" this way too, at least.

Comment: @JoeShipman Effective computation is just a sufficiently rare concept in most homotopy theory (in fact most of modern math) that it's easier to append "effective" whenever it's needed than to specify every time whether a particular computation is effective. I'm sorry if that causes you discomfort, but different fields will have different priorities.

Comment: @JoeShipman: Complaining about topologists’ use of “computation” is like an American going to Italy and complaining that the “cappucino” isn’t like he’s used to from Starbucks.  OK, not quite — that’s an exaggeration — but it’s like complaining that Italian cappucino isn’t like at his nice hipster coffee shop in Brooklyn.  The logician’s usage of “computation” is a good and important one — but the topologists’ looser usage is not merely legitimate, but also *older* than ours, and is essentially what ours was originally derived from.

Comment: I had the impression that a computation could be something carried out by a computor, rather than a computer...

Comment: @TylerLawson Church and Turing had this idea that these two things are equal in power... (assuming enough food, paper, electricity etc)

Answer (score 14):

It may not be any "easier" than Brown's proof, but the work of people like [Francis Sergeraert](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~sergerar/Papers/) and others has created a nice conceptual framework for these types of questions.  See especially the paper, [Effective homotopy of fibrations](http://www-fourier.ujf-grenoble.fr/~sergerar/Papers/AAECC-Effective-Homotopy-of-Fibrations.pdf) by Romero and Sergeraert.  They have also implemented their algorithms in Kenzo.

See also [An algorithm computing homotopy groups](https://idus.us.es/bitstream/handle/11441/125882/1/An%20algorithm%20computing%20homotopy%20groups.pdf?sequence=1) by Pedro Real, which uses the ideas of effective homology to sketch an algorithm for the homotopy groups of spheres specifically.

Comment: I have reviewed all the references.My conclusion: the answer to my original question is “no”.

Comment: It look like the only proofs that homotopy groups of *spheres* are effectively computable are still the same proofs that work for ALL simply connected spaces of finite type via Whitehead or Postnikov towers. Sergeraert and others have given us better tools for managing the process, but you must still iteratively and laboriously kill off homotopy groups one dimension at a time by building higher dimensional complexes, an inherently superexponential process (at least 2^(2^n), at most an exponential tower of height n).

Comment: @JoeShipman I don't know anything about the subject (I'm reading this to learn), but in the question you seemed to say that you wanted a simple proof even if it is inefficient, now you seem to be saying that you don't like this approach because it's inherently superexponential. Is this because its description is necessarily complex, or do you care about efficiency after all?

Comment: @Gro-Tsen I think Joe Shipman is saying that at bottom, these "new" proofs are essentially the same as the original proof. I don't know the subject well, so that may be an accurate assessment. I think the primary value of the modern approach is that it takes a *systematic* approach to computability questions. So for example, while spectral sequences are definitely a "computational tool" in an informal sense, effective homology insists on computability in a formal sense. I think this is clear conceptual advance, but it may not make specific computability proofs "easier."

Comment: Here's another interesting reference I found: [Polynomial-Time Computation of Homotopy Groups and Postnikov Systems in Fixed Dimension](https://doi.org/10.1137/120899029). But again, I don't think it, or the papers it cites, yields an "easier" proof that homotopy groups of spheres are computable.